# Solve matrix equation

Tags: r, math, optimization, equation

I'm studying 'Latent Aspect Rating Analysis' and 
I'm trying to implement the method in r.
I have to calculate 'Beta' which makes the equation equal 0.
Here is the equation

[image]

So I implemented this in r like :

```
update_beta <- function(beta) {

    y <- matrix(nrow = n_words)

    result <- 0
    for (i in 1:n_topics) {
    for (d in 1:length(document)) {
      temp <- 0
      for (j in 1:n_topics) {
        temp <- temp + alpha_d[d,j] * sum(beta[,j]*Wdij[[d]][,j+2]) - r_d[d]
      }
      result <- result + temp[1] * alpha_d[d,i] * Wdij[[d]][,i+2]
    }
    y <- cbind(y, result)
    }
    y <- y[, -1]

    return(y)
}


# Some fake data
n_words <- 10
k <- 3
d <- 8
beta <- runif(n_words * k)  %>% matrix(., ncol = k)
Wdij <- lapply(1:d, function(x) {runif(n_words * k, min = 0, max = 1)  %>% 
matrix(., ncol = k)})
alpha_d <- runif(d * k) %>% matrix(., ncol = k, byrow = T)
r_d <- runif(d)

# Run
library(nleqslv)
beta_result <- nleqslv(beta, update_beta)
```

- Beta is a matrix ( n_words x k ). Wdij is a list which have matrix (
  length(Wdij) is length(document) ).
- Wdij[[d]] is a matrix ( n_words x    k ).
- alpha_d is a matrix ( length(document) x k ).
- r_d is a vector ( length(r_d) is length(document) ).

But, It doesn't look like work well.

Comment: Normally, `beta` should be a vector in the function `nleqslv`, not a matrix. Doesn't it cause a problem ? Why do you say your code doesn't look to work well ? Did you check the solution it provides gives 0 ?

Comment: To nitpick: it is `R` not `r`.  `nleqslv` only accepts functions of a vector.

Comment: Thank you for your answering!!